# Can I fully integrate Wagtail CMS with an Angular frontend?

Tags: python, django, angular, content-management-system, wagtail

So I was needing some kinda of CMS for my project and how I have experience with Django I was thinking of using Wagtail CMS. For example, let's say I'm doing some kinda of blog with Angular 9 as frontend, with user sign up, comments, contact forms and all that stuff. I was reading the Wagtail documentation and the "read_only" API had me worried, my question is simple: Can I **fully** integrate Wagtail CMS with an Angular frontend? With all the functionalities, because if I was using an API I would need POST, PATCH, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to build a full editing interface with Wagtail essentially serving as a database with a thin API on top, it may not be the best choice.

One of the benefits of Wagtail is that it comes with a user interface for editing content and solves a lot of the common CMS use cases (site management, tags, user permissions, multiple content interfaces and rich text editing). If you are planning to build an editor, you might be better suited to look at what else is out there.

It is possible to revise and customise the API to fill in some gaps you may have but out of the box it is read only.

Here are some resources for further investigation though:

- https://davidmburke.com/2019/05/11/using-angular-with-a-headless-wagtail-cms/
- https://learnwagtail.com/tutorials/headless-cms-exposing-orderable-data-and-streamfields/

Some helpful packages

- https://pypi.org/project/wagtail-graphql/
- https://pypi.org/project/wagtail-headless-preview/